# Self join to get the first classID for a report

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2016, self

I have the following table :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable]
(
    [importID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [classID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [priorReportID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [currentReportID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [dateStamp] AS (GETDATE())
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[myTable] ON 
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[myTable] ([importID], [classID], [priorReportID], [currentReportID]) 
VALUES (1, 2069, 3825, 3833), (2, 2069, 3826, 3834),
       (3, 2069, 3827, 3835), (4, 2069, 3832, 3836),
       (5, 2091, 3889, 3890), (6, 2095, 3894, 3895),
       (7, 2098, 3895, 3898), (8, 2098, 3896, 3899),
       (9, 2098, 3897, 3900), (10, 2097, 2190, 2193),
       (11, 2096, 2188, 2190), (12, 2094, 2187, 2188),
       (13, 2093, 2180, 2187)
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[myTable] OFF
GO
```

I am trying to get the first ClassID when a particular report was created.

```
select * 
from mytable

select * 
from mytable
where currentReportID = 3833

select * 
from mytable
where currentReportID = 3825

select * 
from mytable
where currentReportID = 2193

select * 
from mytable
where currentReportID = 2190

select * 
from mytable
where currentReportID = 2188

select * 
from mytable
where currentReportID = 2187

select * 
from mytable
where currentReportID = 2180
```

In the example above: reportID = 2193 was actually created in classID = 2093.

Similarly, reportID = 3833 was created in classID = 2069.

Basically, I need to traverse down the records until there is no more currentReportID = priorReportID condition is satisfied.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: baded on your sampe ... show your expected  result  .. as  tabular text .. and what mean " first classID  "  ..?? the class  related to the lower importID??

Comment: i assume you use SQL Server (MSSQL) ? As the SQL tag is not meant for SQL Server (MSSQL) on this website but for ANSI/ISO SQL standards valid code which this code is clearly not..

Comment: This is MS SQL Server 2016.